# Can I put a relative pronoun in a apposition clause?

Tags: relative-pronouns, relative-clauses

Instead of "My son, Mike, is sleeping", can I say "My son, who is Mike, is sleeping"?

And if not, why?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I guess it's grammatically correct, but it's not something I would ever say, because it sounds very unnatural.  Is there a specific reason that you want to say it?

Comment: There's no reason, but I wanna find the possibility.

Comment: No, but see my comment to Shaona, below.

Comment: As @stangdon said, I doubt anyone would say this. "My son Mike is sleeping." is more than sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use *who is* in the way you have stated, it usually means you're giving details about that person. 
Example:

> My son, who is a painter, is...

Just for  mentioning names, which specify a person, we don't use it that way.

> My son, Mike..

is enough.

Comment: Interestingly, some grammars do use the term 'appositive' instead of 'non-restrictive' for such relative clause. But it's best avoided since the integrated vs supplementary contrast applies to apposition as well as relative clauses, e.g. "my brother the heart surgeon" (integrated) and "my brother, the heart surgeon"  (supplementary).